# how to retain user input data after validation using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am creating a web app using codeigniter and I am trying to retain user input data on a login form I am using the set value function but the user input is disappearing.

```
<?php echo form_open('Authentication/login_check',$attributes);?>



 <div class="medium-12 columns">    
<?php 
echo form_label('Email'); 
$data = array(

'class'=>'form-control',
'name'=>'email',
'id'=> 'email',
'placeholder'=>'Email',
'value' => set_value('email')
);

echo form_input($data);
?>
</div> 

<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Comment: Are you loading the ci form helper?

Comment: yeah im autoloading it

Comment: hey if you haven't figured this out - post your controller code and all of your view code. "Trying to get property of non-object" error -- could be a completely different issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can load form helper in :

**application/config/autoload.php**

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('form');
```

You can set your form look like :

```
<?php echo form_open('authentication/login_check', '', array('id' => (!empty($attributes)) ? $attributes->id : 0)); ?>
<div class="medium-12 columns">    
<?php 
echo form_label('Email'); 
$data = array(

'class'=>'form-control',
'name'=>'email',
'id'=> 'email',
'placeholder'=>'Email',
'value' => set_value('email',($this->input->post('email')) ? $this->input->post('email') : ((!empty($attributes)) ? $attributes->email : ''))
);

echo form_input($data);
?>
</div> 

<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Comment: i get this error Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: You can set before attributes in controller with data.

Comment: what do you mean before attributes

Comment: You can set in controller side attributes value.

Comment: do you mean passing a default value to the view

Comment: Yes if you can set value before or after validation of login form.

Comment: can u give me an example